# SQLite/JDBC inner join

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I have found what appears to be a bug in the SQLite JDBC driver, but I thought I'd see if someone could spot any boneheaded errors on my part.  I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SKU_ATTR_VALUE.*, 
    Product.ProductID 
FROM 
    SKU_ATTR_VALUE 
    INNER JOIN SKU 
    ON SKU_ATTR_VALUE.SkuID=SKU.SkuID 
    INNER JOIN Product 
    ON SKU.ProductID=Product.ProductID 
WHERE Product.ProductID=?
```

Pretty simple.  I can run this in the SQLite database browser, replacing the ? with 1, and it returns 18 rows, which is just what it should do.  Only 18 rows match the condition.  But when I run this in Java, and pass in the value 1, I get 817 values back.  And that's not a Cartesian join;  there are 864 possible values in SKU_ATTR_VALUE.  The results I get back have at least one value for each record in Product too...so I really can't imagine what is happening.

I've been looking at this a while and I'm completely stumped.  Googling it doesn't seem to turn anything up.  Yes, I'm sure that I'm running the Java query against the same SQLite database as in the SQLite browser.

The name of the SQLite jar is sqlitejdbc-v056.jar.  It is based on SQLite 3.6.14.2.

Here is the Java code that sets up the query:

```
String sql = "SELECT SKU_ATTR_VALUE.*, Product.ProductID " + 
             "FROM SKU_ATTR_VALUE " + 
             "     INNER JOIN SKU ON SKU_ATTR_VALUE.SkuID=SKU.SkuID " + 
             "     INNER JOIN Product ON SKU.ProductID=Product.ProductID " + 
             "WHERE Product.ProductID=?";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, productID);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I've furthered determined that the problem is when I join the SKU and SKU_ATTR_VALUE tables.  The SKU and PRODUCT tables join OK.  I also saw that, when I would copy the query into the database browser built into NetBeans, the problem showed up there as well.  So then I tried adding both an ON clause, and I'd add s.SkuID=sav.SkuID in the WHERE clause.  This fixed the problem in the NetBeans db browser, but not in the code (which is running in NetBeans).  I've concluded that yes, this is a bug, and I'm moving away from SQLite.  I don't trust it now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) section "5.0 Joins" : you can try to rewrite your query like this :

```
SELECT 
  SKU_ATTR_VALUE.*, 
  Product.ProductID 
FROM 
  Product, SKU, SKU_ATTR_VALUE
WHERE 
Product.ProductID=?
AND SKU.ProductID=Product.ProductID 
AND SKU_ATTR_VALUE.SkuID=SKU.SkuID
```